# Como alterar o background de um botão ao ser clicado?

Tags: java, android

Preciso alterar o background de um botão ao ser clicado.
Aqui está o código que tentei:

```
private Button btn;
private int colorFlag = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela2);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (colorFlag == 0) {
                btn.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.curisoidade_desligado);
                colorFlag = 1;
            } else {
                btn.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.curisoidade);
                colorFlag = 0;
            }
        }
```

Ao ser clicado o botão de id (button7), deveria trocar para a imagem curisoidade_desligado, porém, não está ocorrendo.
Além da main, devo adicionar algo no xml?

Xml:

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="37dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="47dp"
    android:background="@drawable/curisoidade"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.97"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.087" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você não está a alterar o *background* do botão. Para isso deve usar o método `setBackground()`

Em vez de

```
btn.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.curisoidade_desligado);
```

use

```
btn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.curisoidade_desligado));
```

**Nota:**

O método `getDrawable()` foi considerado obsoleto na API 22.

Se minSdk for 21 ou superior use

```
btn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.curisoidade_desligado, getTheme()));
```

Caso seja inferior e esteja a utilizar a biblioteca de compatibilidade use

```
btn.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.curisoidade_desligado))
```

---

No entanto o "correcto" seria usar um [ToggleButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html), já que ele reproduz o comportamento de um botão com dois estados: ligado/desligado.

Para que ele use as suas imagens crie um selector na pasta drawable:

***toggle_selector.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/R.drawable.curisoidade" android:state_checked="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/R.drawable.curisoidade_desligado" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

No layout, substitua o Button por um ToggleButton e use como background esse selector:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="37dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="47dp"
    android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.97"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.087" 
    android:textOff=""
    android:textOn=""

/>
```

No java, não precisa mais de usar aquele `if`, a mudança de imagem será automática.